# Remove section numbering from tocloft without using \section*{}

Tags: sectioning, numbering, tocloft, article

I am trying to remove the section numbering from tocloft, but only on some entries. Example how I want it:
[image: Example how I want it]
.

This is how I remove it now:

```
\section*{Discussion} \label{discussion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{discussion}}
```

But with this method, the links are not included in the pdf navigation menu and it is a messy solution in my opinion.

I tried the following, but it is only for Book sections (I use article):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{\end{lrbox}}
\makeatother
```

I can suppress the section numbering in the paper itself using:
'''
\renewcommand{\prefix@section}{ }
'''

To summarise, I want to remove 8, 9 and 10 from the example below:

[image: Remove this]

While using the normal:

```
\section{Discussion} \label{discussion}
```

I hope anyone can help because I can't figure it out. It seems like such a simple thing to do. If I need to provide more information I am happy to do so. Thank you in advance!

Working code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{nameref}

%% # TOC CONFIG #
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of contents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}


\begin{document}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}  
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{5}    
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

    \let\oldthesection=\thesection
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{}

    % Without before
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{}
    \section{section one no nr before} \label{1nonr}


    % Normal sections
    \let\thesection=\oldthesection
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \section{section one}

    \section{section two}
    \subsection{subsection one}

    \section{section three}
    \subsection{subsection one}
    \subsection{subsection two}

    % Without after
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{}
    \section{section one no nr} \label{1nonr}

    \section{section two no nr} \label{2nonr}
    \subsection{subsection one} \label{2snonr}
\end{document}
```

Picture:
[image: Picture with how it works now]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please please post a small, yet complete code of what you've tried, that we can compile?

Comment: Hi @Bernard, thanks for your response! I added the code and just figured out that the last command `\renewcommand{\thesection}{}` works! This command sort of destroys the numbering but it can be reset using \let\oldthesection=\thesection and afterwards  \let\thesection=\oldthesection

Comment: \label requires a counter (\refstepcounter) and \section* doesn't use one.  Try \hypertarget and \hyperlink instead.  Or add \refstepcounter{section}.